# Pass parameter value from my implementation service to my RestController java springboot

Tags: java, spring-restcontroller

I'm having a trouble passing the value of error i get when im returning the results of a table.

I have a method in my ServiceImpl class which return results for the table and also counts the amount of  errors.

```
public List<Flow>  getAllProcessContextWithCriteriaAndFlowCode(
            String startDate, String endDate, String flowCode) {



        List<FlowDto> flowDtos = new ArrayList<>(500);
        flowDtos = processContextRepository
                .fetch(startDate,
                        endDate, flowCode);

        List<Flow> flows = new ArrayList();

        // bodyguard
        if (flowDtos == null || flowDtos.size() == 0) {
            return flows;
        }

        int counter = 0;
        StringBuilder idFonctionnelBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        FlowDto currentFlowDto = null;
        FlowState flowState = new FlowState();
        FlowDto nextFlowDto = null;
        Flow flowTemp = null;
        Map<String, String> mapFlowIdsAndIdF = new HashMap<>();
        int iNbreError = 0;
        String sTempError = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < flowDtos.size(); i++) {

            currentFlowDto = flowDtos.get(i);

            if ((i + 1) < flowDtos.size()) {
                nextFlowDto = flowDtos.get(i + 1);
                if (((nextFlowDto.getFlowId()
                        .equals(currentFlowDto.getFlowId())))) {
                    idFonctionnelBuilder.append(currentFlowDto.getIdf() + ", ");
                    continue;

                } else {
                    flowTemp = new Flow();

                    flowTemp.setFlowId(currentFlowDto.getFlowId());

                    flowTemp.setLogRole(currentFlowDto.getLogRole());


                    Date date = null;
                    try {
                        date = inputFormat.parse(currentFlowDto
                                .getContextTime());
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    flowTemp.setContextTime(outputFormat.format(date));

                    if (currentFlowDto.getLogRole() != null) {
                        iNbreError++;
                        flowTemp.setNbreError(iNbreError);
                    } else {
                        flowTemp.setNbreError(iNbreError);
                    }



                    flowTemp.setNbreError(iNbreError);
                    flows.add(flowTemp);


                }
            } else {

                flowTemp = new Flow();



                if (currentFlowDto.getLogRole() != null) {

                    iNbreError++;
                    flowTemp.setNbreError(iNbreError);
                } else {
                    flowTemp.setNbreError(iNbreError);
                }
                flowTemp.setContextTime(outputFormat.format(date));


                flows.add(flowTemp);
            }
        }


        LOGGER.info("[ getAllProcessContextWithCriteriaAndFlowCode ] iNbreError    : "
                + iNbreError);
        getNbreError(iNbreError);
        return flows;
    }
```

Then i have another method in the same class ServiceImpl who get the number of errors and set it in a variable, the result print is always the right one here.

```
public int getNbreError( int iNbreError){
        System.out.println("HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH");
            System.out.println(iNbreError);
        setCountError(iNbreError);
        System.out.println("HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH");
        System.out.println(countError);
        return countError;
    }
```

What i want to do is send this value(counterror) to my RestController which is in another class called RestController so i can send it to my angular front

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/nbreError")
    public int getCountError() {
        FMServiceImpl flows = new FMServiceImpl();
        int countError = 0;
        int iNbreError = 0;


        return fmService.getNbreError( iNbreError);

    }
}
```

Actually the result is always 0.
Thanks for your any help or advice :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use *getMethod* to modify data, check principle **Command–query separation (CQS)**
2. Don't create FMServiceImpl manually,  Inject FMServiceImpl as dependence to your controller. in spring, Service keeps the state by default.